# Saving multi-files which is imported using importdata

Tags: matlab

I am using below code to read multi-files using `importdata`and `for`commands. The problem that I have is only the last file is saved . I got from `importdata`one matrix but it should be 6 matrices

How I can save all matrices that I imported?

```
myFolder = 'M:\Matlab\Experiment-Result\read all';
filePattern = fullfile(myFolder, '*.dat')
theFiles = dir(filePattern);
for k = 1 : length(theFiles)
    baseFileName = theFiles(k).name;
    fullFileName = fullfile(myFolder, baseFileName);
    fprintf(1, 'Now reading %s\n', fullFileName);
    Data = importdata(fullFileName);
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple reason.  `Data` keeps getting overwritten at each iteration of the loop and so once the `for` loop stops, only the data read in from the last iteration gets saved.  If you want to save the data per iteration, I don't know how your data is structured, but to make it the most adaptable, make `Data` a cell array:

```
myFolder = 'M:\Matlab\Experiment-Result\read all';
filePattern = fullfile(myFolder, '*.dat')
theFiles = dir(filePattern);
Data = cell(1,numel(theFiles)); %// Change
for k = 1 : length(theFiles)
    baseFileName = theFiles(k).name;
    fullFileName = fullfile(myFolder, baseFileName);
    fprintf(1, 'Now reading %s\n', fullFileName);
    Data{k} = importdata(fullFileName); %// Change
end
```

To access the k<sup>th</sup> data file, simply do:

```
out = Data{k};
```

You can then use `out` as if it were a matrix and index / slice into it in however manner you see fit.

Comment: Thank you! when I want to use row 2 from third matrix how I can call that row?

Comment: @Ali easy. First get the third matrix, then access the second row: `out = Data{3}; row = out(2,:);`